# SCSS: simple hover issue

Tags: css, sass, hover

This seems fairly simple, but I am not sure what is wrong.

I am trying to toggle the `visibility` attribute by hovering the div element as so:

```
<div class="tooltip">
  <span class="tooltip-text">
    Hello world!
  </span>
</div>
```

with SCSS:

```
.tooltip{
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3f51b5;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  .tooltip-text{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    &:hover {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
}
```

I am assuming nesting is not correct at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned the `:hover` CSS to `.tooltip-text`, which is hidden, so you can't hover it. You need to assign the `:hover` pseudo class selector to `.tooltip` and then list the `.tooltip-text` selector after it to target it's visibility. Like this

```css
.tooltip{
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3f51b5;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
  &:hover .tooltip-text {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .tooltip-text{
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Alejandro fo sho!